# NDK build - specify linker settings per architecture

Tags: android-ndk

My Application.mk is set to build arm as well as x86 shared libraries:

APP_ABI :- armeabi-v7a x86

I have prebuilt openssl static libraries:

```
libcrypto_v7a.a
libcrypto_x86.a
libssl_v7a.a
libssl_x86.a
```

These files have been copied to jni/inc directory:

Would appreciate your help in setting up Android.mk such that it picks up proper library to link with:

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog -L$(LOCAL_PATH)/inc/ -lcrypto_v7a -lssl_v7a
```

or

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog -L$(LOCAL_PATH)/inc/ -lcrypto_x86 -lssl_x86
```

Perhaps there is a $(ARCH) kind of variable defined that I could use to my advantage:

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog -L$(LOCAL_PATH)/inc/ -lcrypto_$(ARCH) -lssl_$(ARCH)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using `ifeq` and `TARGET_ARCH`?

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -L$(LOCAL_PATH)/inc/ 
ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH),arm)
  LOCAL_LDLIBS += -lcrypto_v7a -lssl_v7a
else
  ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH),x86)
    LOCAL_LDLIBS += -lcrypto_x86 -lssl_x86
  endif
endif
```

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you for your help. Good to know that TARGET_ARCH macro is available.

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative is:

```
MY_LDLIBS_arm := -lcrypto_v7a -lssl_v7a
MY_LDLIBS_x86 := -lcrypto_x86 -lssl_x86
MY_LDLIBS_mips := ...

LOCAL_LDLIBS += $(MY_LDLIBS_$(TARGET_ARCH))
```

Which is easier to read and write.

Comment: +1 but I had to think for a second and digest which means it isn't trivial.

Comment: That's a really good alternative, especially as this notation is becoming the norm in upcoming NDK releases: it's already used in AOSP for the CFLAGS: https://github.com/android/platform_external_skia/blob/master/Android.mk

Comment: It is strange that while it is natively supported for CFLAGS, I couldn't find such use for LDLIBS.